# Pass list of class type to the Oracle procedure c#

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle12c

I wanted to call oracle stored procedure having collection as parameter from C#. I was able to make a call to procedure via array/list(1 dimensional only) from c#, but now I want to pass list of complex type, the moment I added that I am getting OracleParameter.Value is invalid error . Below is the sample :

```
OracleCommand comm = new OracleCommand("Schema.PACK_INQUIRY.ProcEmpUDFArray_Test", "Connection");
                comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            List<Employee> EmpList = new List<Employee>()
            {
                new Employee() { City = "City1", Name="Emp1" },
                new Employee() {City = "City2", Name="Emp2" }
            };


            OracleParameter param1 = new OracleParameter("Param1", OracleDbType.Varchar2, EmpList.Count, EmpList, ParameterDirection.Input);
            param1.ArrayBindStatus = Enumerable.Repeat(OracleParameterStatus.Success, EmpList.Count()).ToArray();
            param1.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
            comm.Parameters.Add(param1);
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Below is the class code

```
public class Employee
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string City { get; set; }
        }
```

Below is the oracle code

```
create or replace  type EMPTEST AS OBJECT
    (    
        Name   varchar2(50),    
        City          varchar2(50)
    );

type T_EMPUDF_ARRAY is table of EMPTEST;

PROCEDURE ProcEmpUDFArray_Test( Param1 IN  T_EMPUDF_ARRAY)
    AS
    out_ORAERRORMSG   VARCHAR2(100);
    BEGIN      
    insert into test values ('1');
     commit;
        if Param1.count > 0 THEN
            FOR i IN 1 .. Param1.count LOOP
                insert into test values (Param1(i).Name);
            END LOOP;
        END IF;
     commit;
      EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
     out_ORAERRORMSG := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 50);
     insert into test values (out_ORAERRORMSG);
     commit;
END ProcEmpUDFArray_Test;
```

I added the code insert into test values ('1'); just to check if my call is getting into the proc or not. I checked it is not. Can't I pass complex list type to oracle procedure.
Also, I read on Oracle
**Associative arrays are single-dimensional, unbounded, sparse collections of homogeneous elements.
First, an associative array is single-dimensional. It means that an associative array has a single column of data in each row, which is similar to a one-dimension array.**

Comment: If it were possible, you would have to set `param1.UdtTypeName = "EMPTEST";` but without `OracleDbType.Object`, it looks like you're out of luck. The unmanaged provider had it but the managed one doesn't. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57617335/odp-net-managed-driver-has-no-oracledbtype-object-whats-the-equivalent

Comment: thanks @madreflection!! It looks like I have to rely on xml now i.e to convert list/datatable to xml and then pass that xml to stored proc. 
or I am thinking of making a one dimensional list from multi dimensional list using comma separated columns